# Nsolve a parametric equation and using the result of NSolve in another equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics

I have the following equation:

```
(2 r)/(1 - 1/r + r^2 - r^(-1 + b)) - (r^2 (1/r^2 + 2 r - r^(-2 + b) (-1 +
b)))/(1 - 1/r + r^2 - r^(-1 + b))^2 = 0
```

I need to find r for 0<b<1, and use r to calculate and plot F:

```
F= r/Sqrt[1 - 1/r^(1 - b) - 1/r]
```

To plot F with respect to b. First I defined a function R[b], which numerically solves my first equation and gives me r for each value of b, as the following:

```
R[b_] := NSolve[-((r^2 (1/r^2 + 2 r - (-1 + b) r^(-2 + b)))/(1 - 1/r + r^2 - 
   r^(-1 + b))^2) + (2 r)/(1 - 1/r + r^2 - r^(-1 + b)) == 0, r]
```

Now, I need to use R[b_] to calculate and plot F, which is:

```
 F= R[b]/Sqrt[1 - 1/R[b]^(1 - b) - 1/R[b]]
```

How can I plot F?

Answer (score 3):

First, simplify your expression:

```
ex = (2 r)/(1 - 1/r + r^2 - 
      r^(-1 + b)) - (r^2 (1/r^2 + 2 r - r^(-2 + b) (-1 + b)))/(1 - 
       1/r + r^2 - r^(-1 + b))^2;
ex = Simplify[ex]
```

[image]

If this expression should be zero, the numerator must be zero:

```
eq=r^2 (-3 + 2 r + (-3 + b) r^b) ==0
```

That means either r is zero or the second term. If r is zero, b is not determined. Therefore the second term must be zero:

```
(-3 + 2 r + (-3 + b) r^b) ==0
```

Note that this determines r only for b<1 Otherwise we get: -3+2 -2==0. And it is to be expected that near b==1 we will have some troubles.

We may use this to get r as a function of b:

```
fr[b_] := r /. FindRoot[-3 + 2 r + (-3 + b) r^b == 0, {r, 1}][[1]]
```

And with this we may define the final function and plot it:

```
ff[b_] := Module[ {r = fr[b]}, r/Sqrt[1 - 1/r^(1 - b) - 1/r]]
Plot[ff[b], {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

It is obvious that the function diverges toward 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is really helpful. If I do not simplify my equation, is it possible to use result of NSolve for plot?

Comment: In your plot, the value 1 in the horizontal axis corresponds to 35 in vertical axis. But in the plot by @DanielLichtblau, which is in the below post, 1 in horizontal axis corresponds to 5. where does this difference come from?

Comment: Divide the horizontal axis of DanielLichtblau by the factor 10 to get b, since he generated points with distance 0.1 with `Table[func[x], {x, 0., .9, 0.1}]`

Answer (score 1):

A little slow but can do like this.

```
rr[b_?NumberQ] := 
 First@NSolveValues[-((r^2 (1/r^2 + 2 r - (-1 + b) r^(-2 + b)))/(1 - 
           1/r + r^2 - r^(-1 + b))^2) + (2 r)/(1 - 1/r + r^2 - 
        r^(-1 + b)) == 0, r]
func[b_] := rr[b]/Sqrt[1 - 1/rr[b]^(1 - b) - 1/rr[b]];

ListPlot[Table[func[x], {x, 0., .9, .1}]]
```

[image]

It is quite slow to find values for spacing of .01 though.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful. is not it possible to plot func[x] as a continuous line?

Comment: The method by @DanielHuber seems fine.